# How to find volume of two curves about an axis

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, wolfram-alpha

**Question-**

$R$ is the region bounded by $y=\sqrt{x}$ and $y=\frac{x}{2}$ and this region is rotated around $x=4$. What is the volume?

**My attempt**

$$\left|\pi\int_0^2 ((4-2y)^2-(4-y^2)^2) \right| \, dy$$

I got $20.106$

However, Wolfram alpha received something else as in the photo posted

Am I doing something wrong?[image]

Comment: hmm.. what you did seems fine. I plugged your values into wolfram in two separate steps. Specifically, I looked at the volume of the rotation of $y=\sqrt{x}$ about $x=4$ on the interval $x\in [0,4]$ and then subtracted the volume from the other function. That got me exactly what you have